# Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that starts a foreground service as follows:

In the calling activity:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

And in the service's onStart():

```
startForeground(...
```

At some point, the service needs to display a message to the user, then transition back to the "home screen", which is defined as the activity marked with the LAUNCHER intent-filter (but it could be any activity for this example). I accomplish this by creating an Intent inside of MyService to an activity with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowMessageActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Show me to the user");
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

From this new activity, I display a message, then attempt to take the user back to the "home screen" by creating a new Intent with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:

```
finish();
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

The issue I seem to be having is that since the MessageActivity was created with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it seems to be on it's own activity stack, so that when I get back to the "home screen", the back button takes me to the previous activity on the stack instead of exiting the app (as this should be the only activity on the stack).

Here's a better picture of what I'm experiencing:

1. Launch app which creates MainActivity
2. MainActivity starts MyService
3. User performs some action which causes them to transition to AnotherActivity
4. MyService creates MessageActivity
5. MessageActivity takes user back to MainActivity
6. User clicks the back button
7. Instead of exising the app (as this should be the only activity on the stack), the user sees AnotherActivity

I tried to create the MessageActivity from MyService without using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but this produces an exception which states FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY is required.

My question is, how do I get an activity created with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to clear the activity stack for the entire app. The desired behaviour is that once I transition from MessageActivity to MainActivity, that MainActivity is the ONLY activity on the stack.